# In Odoo13, how can I compare two datetime fields of a record in search domain?

Tags: odoo-13

In Odoo13 I have a model that has two Datetime fields.

e.g.

```
start_date = fields.Datetime("Start Date")

end_date = fields.Datetime("End Date")
```

I try to search for records by comparing the two fields:

`results = self.env['model'].search([('start_date', '>', 'end_date')])`

I receive the following error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "end_date"

Comparing a Datetime field with a string date e.g. '2023-01-01' works as expected.

Is there a way I can directly compare these two fields in a search domain?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it. Odoo domains builds the SQL Query using values on the left side of the domain tuples, so no way to reference a column. In order to reach what you want you need to execute a direct SQL Query using `self.env.cr.execute(query)`

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways:

1. Using filtered on all records of your custom model:

```py
    class my_model(models.Model):
        _name = "my.model"

    def get_start_greater_end(self):
        res_records = self.env['my.model'].search([]).filtered(lambda rec: rec.start_date>rec.end_date)
        return res_records
```

2. Or executing a raw SQL-query to return the matching record(s)-id:

```py
    class my_model(models.Model):
        _name = "my.model"
    
    def get_start_greater_end(self):
    
        query = """SELECT id FROM my_model m 
                WHERE m.start_date > m.end_date"""
        self._cr.execute(query)
        qry_res = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        #my_models_list_ids = [rec['id'] for rec in qry_res]
        #return my_models_list_ids
        res_records = self.env['my.model'].browse(set(rec['id'] for rec in qry_res))
        return res_records
```